# What is the purpose of having fewer holes/free electrons in the collector region of a BJT?

Tags: circuit-analysis, semiconductors

The functionality of the NPN/PNP sandwich as a means for the base current to control the one directional flow of current makes sense to me.

However, I'm struggling to understand the details of the Base/Collector region (take the NPN for instance). Does the overwhelming annihilation of holes in the P region cause the depletion region in the Base/Collector junction to disappear? Does the transistor effectively turn into a single N doped semiconductor? And why is less doping needed for the collector region, how and why does that help?

I'm wondering whether there is also any basic 'blackbox' equation for the transistor in the context of a Kirchoff compliant circuit. Such as the law of resistor, capacitor and inductor?

My end goal is to understand from the ground up, the functionality of a constant current LED driver, but my approach as a physics background is to understand the basics first as much as necessary.

Comment: Perhaps it will help you understand the transistor principle better if you start from the correct assumption that it is the base-emitter voltage (and NOT the base current) that determines the collector current? In this context, it is width of the depletion zone (as a function of the voltage across it) which matters primarily.